# Chain multiple fixtures pytest/unittest hybrid

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, fixtures

I am working with a code base which which is mostly written with unittest. The tests are run with pytest. I am trying to simplify the tests by parameterizing some of them. To work towards this goal, I am trying to learn how to use pytest fixtures and refactor some of the existing unittest-based tests. The current tests have a global fixture in conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def register_cleanup():
    yield True
    print("cleaning up database")
```

Now I want to add a fixture which is specific to one of my test modules, something along the lines of

```
@pytest.fixture()
def foo_fixture():
    print("setup fixture")
    yield
    print("tear down fixture")


class Foo(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print('unittest setUp()')

    def test(self):
        print('test')
```

However, the `print()` statements in this module fixture never execute. As an intermediate step, I am keeping the unittest-based structure and adding to it. Is it possible to get this working the way I want or do I need to scrap unittest altogether and go directly to pytest.

Comment: Where would you expect this fixture to be used?  Did you want to turn on `autouse=True` here as well?  In general, fixtures are only executed when they are a parameter to the test, and are less of generic cleanup mechanisms than scoped assumptions

Comment: @Cireo Do you mean I should add  `autouse=True` to `foo_fixture()` similarly to `register_cleanup()`?

Comment: @Cireo Feel free to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to mark it:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("foo_fixture")
class Foo(unittest.TestCase):
    ...
```

Note: you may have more than one `conftest.py`.  Put the more specific fixture into this test subdirectory's `conftest.py`.

Comment: Thank you. I must have missed the necessary detail as I'm skimming the docs.

Comment: Unfortunately all of the tests are in a single directory. As I refactor, I will look into organizing them better.

Answer (score 0):

Where would you expect this fixture to be used?

Did you want to turn on `autouse=True` here as well? In general, fixtures are only executed when they are a parameter to the test, and are less of generic cleanup mechanisms than scoped assumptions.  By turning on `autouse` for this fixture you will essentially add an extra setup-cleanup step for the current module:

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-xunit-setup-on-steroids

> Here is how autouse fixtures work in other scopes:
>
> autouse fixtures obey the scope= keyword-argument: if an autouse
>   fixture has scope='session' it will only be run once, no matter where
>   it is defined. scope='class' means it will be run once per class, etc.
>   if an autouse fixture is defined in a test module, all its test
>   functions automatically use it. if an autouse fixture is defined in a
>   conftest.py file then all tests in all test modules below its
>   directory will invoke the fixture. lastly, and please use that with
>   care: if you define an autouse fixture in a plugin, it will be invoked
>   for all tests in all projects where the plugin is installed. This can
>   be useful if a fixture only anyway works in the presence of certain
>   settings e. g. in the ini-file. Such a global fixture should always
>   quickly determine if it should do any work and avoid otherwise
>   expensive imports or computation.

[Adaptied comment into an answer]